# I would like to control my Traxxas Stampede with a raspbery pi

Tags: pi-zero, remote, radio, signal

So i want to make basically a glove where when i tilt my hand it will turn the car. (I'm going to just have simple buttons for forward and back so I only need to focus on one tilt plane) I plan on ordering the Raspberry Pi Zero and an ADXL345 accelerometer.

the issue I am running in to is I can find tutorials for how to code and how the accelerometer works all over the internet, but I cant find any on how to control the car. all the tutorials I'm finding are all cars built from scratch to run off of a raspberry pi or involve modifying the car in some way. What I would like to do is leave the car untouched and somehow replace the controller with a raspberry pi.

so basically what I'm asking is how would I go about getting my Pi to send the proper signals the controller would have. What parts and modules do I need for the pie to transmit them? what device do I need to detect the signals and find out what the controller itself is sending? is there anything else i need? or can i just open up the controller and somehow take the signal chip out of that and hook it to the pi?

I'm very new to this and this will actually be my first project, yeah i know its pretty complex for a beginner but anything you can tell me will be of great help, Thank You!

Comment: I have been using Rpi1,2,3,4,z, zw, and now pico. I have been playing with MEMS accelero/gyro/magneto stuff, including ADXL345. I have been playing with different Stepping, BLDC, DC motor controllers, including now TB6612FNG.  I have been playing with RF control, including 433MHz and 2.4GHz stuff, 2WD amd 4WD, with different motors, including now TM310 with metal gears. You might like to skim my project blog to get a rough idea or reference top your project. https://forum.pi-top.com/t/making-a-rpi-pico-based-smart-vehicle/924. Please feel free to ask me newbie question. Happy learning, cheers.

Comment: I don't think this is a suitable question for this site.  It would be perfectly acceptable at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/

Comment: For newbies I would suggest to start off with popular toy motors such as TT130, motor drivers such as L298N, and Acceleros with MPU6050.  They are popular, so you can easily find tutorials and references.  BTW, I have another 4WD project in Rpi.org.forum.  You might also find newbie references there. Re: Choosing motors (N20, TT130 motors), Motor Controller (TB6612FNG), MPU6050 (gyroscope and accelerometer), 4WD Assembly and Testing, Rpi.Org.Forum, 2019mar13
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=234304&hilit=tt130+motor. Happy learning. Cheers..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your Traxxas seems using Titan 12T gear motor.  It seems an ordinary brush DC motor, but much powerful than TT130 toy. You might like to start with using L298N to drive first (a) TT130, (b) if OK, then try our luck with Titan.   (1) Traxxas 1/10 Slash 2WD TITAN 12T BRUSHED 550 MOTOR & 19T PINION GEAR
https://www.amazon.com/Traxxas-Slash-Titan-Brushed-Pinion/dp/B076NYMNH1,

(2) Stampede (36054-1) Transmission Assembly Exploded View
https://traxxas.com/explodedviews/Stampede-36054-1-Transmission-Assembly,

(3) Titan 12T Modified Motor
https://traxxas.com/products/parts/motors/titan12T.

Comment: unfortunately i was unable to find a way to hack the controller so I think I will start my raspberry pi adventures with a simpler project by setting up LEDs and seeing what I can do with those, thank you everyone for the answers you provided! if somebody could tell me how to close this thread that would be great!